# SwiftUI: How to align Path to a .firstTextBaseline in a same way as Image(systemName: ...)?

Tags: swiftui

I have layout of icon (`Image(systemName: ...)` SF symbol) and text pairs, aligned to the `.firstTextBaseline`.

This works well, and the symbols are aligned with text onto a same baseline.

Now I would like to replace on of the icons with custom drawn `Path`, but that has broken the alignment - it seems that for the Path, the layout system treats the bottom edge as baseline.

How can I tell the layout system to use a different offset from the bottom as a baseline (so that the arrow would look aligned to the text baseline)?

Illustration:

[image]

EDIT: I found [.baselineOffset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/baselineoffset(_:)/), but it seems to only be supported from iOS 16 for Paths :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that before iOS 16 enabled adding `.baselineOffset` to every view, a solution could be

```swift
.alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.firstTextBaseline) { d in d.height * 0.75 }
```

Here's a great resource explaining the [.alignmentGuide](https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/).